# Cannot find the ground bar in the panel

Tags: electrical-panel

I am going to add a new 240v outlet, but I cannot find the ground bar in the panel. It looks the ground line is connected to the neutral bar(white line) directly.

See panel photo below

[image: panel]
[image: Panel]

Comment: If putting a new circuit in a garage and will use a receptacle/outlet, will need to have a GCFI.  There are probably a few other places in the home/house that also requires GFCI protection.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the main panel, then the panel maker just combined ground and neutral bars into one instead of having two separate but bonded together bars.

Quite a few panel makers will have two bars, but they will be connected together, either by a wire or the metal of the panel itself.

In sub panels(extra panels) then you need separated and unbonded(not connected together) neutral and ground bar.